# VueJS data not reactive mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an API which returns all the currency rate, i used a function `getRate()` on `mounted` but `rate['usd']` is `undefined`, if i call the function again on that page it returns the actual data, i tried `beforeCreated` `beforeMounted` but they are not working, how to make the data reactive on load or am i doing something wrong?

```
<template>
  <span v-text="rate['usd']"></span>
</template>

<script>
data() {
    return {
        rate: null
    }
},
methods: {
    getRate() {
        this.$vs.loading()
        this.$http.post('wallet/rate' ,[])
        .then(response => {
            for(let key in response.data.data.data){
                this.rate[response.data.data.data[key].name] = response.data.data.data[key].value
            }
            this.$vs.loading.close()
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.$vs.loading.close()
        })
    },
},
mounted() {
  this.getRate()
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
<template>
  <span v-text="rate.usd"></span>
</template>

<script>
data() {
    return {
        rate: null
    }
},
methods: {
    getRate() {
        const rate = {}
        this.$vs.loading()
        this.$http.post('wallet/rate' ,[])
        .then(response => {
            for(let key in response.data.data.data){
                rate[response.data.data.data[key].name] = response.data.data.data[key].value
            }
            this.$vs.loading.close()
            this.rate = rate
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.$vs.loading.close()
        })
    },
},
mounted() {
  this.getRage()
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think it's because `this.rate` never changed in your example, it is the same reference to an object the while time, so Vue didn't see the need to update. In my example, I created a new object and replaced `this.rate` with the new one.